# Where can I find (or make) Material Design Icon set for dense layouts (20dp, desktop)

Tags: svg, icons, material-design, desktop

Google Material Design guidance [says](https://material.io/design/iconography/system-icons.html#grid-keyline-shapes):

> On desktop, when the mouse and keyboard are the primary input methods, measurements may be scaled down to 20dp.

Moreover, I see that new Gmail uses 20dp-sized icons
(screenshot was taken on non-high DPI display):

---

[image: 20dp-sized icons used in Gmail]

---

At the same time, I cannot find MD icons of this size anywhere. [Google MD icons](https://material.io/tools/icons) only offers 18dp, 24dp and bigger. Same thing in the [repository](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons). But I need exactly the size of 20dp.

I tried to use [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io) to change grid to 20px and tried to use icon font with the size of 20px. Both methods produce blurry icons, of course.

**Where can I find them?
Or, how can I up/downscale existing MD icons?**

**UPDATE**:

This is the original icon from Gmail (20px):
`https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/archive_black_20dp.png`

[image: archive icon]

And this is SVG, with the 24px and the desired 20px size. 
On my non-high DPI screen this 20px SVG is blurry.
[image: archive icons]

```html
<svg width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>account balance</title>
<g id="g">
    <path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'></path>
    <path d='M20.54 5.23l-1.39-1.68C18.88 3.21 18.47 3 18 3H6c-.47 0-.88.21-1.16.55L3.46 5.23C3.17 5.57 3 6.02 3 6.5V19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6.5c0-.48-.17-.93-.46-1.27zM12 17.5L6.5 12H10v-2h4v2h3.5L12 17.5zM5.12 5l.81-1h12l.94 1H5.12z'></path>
</g>
</svg>

<svg width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>account balance</title>
<use xlink:href="#g" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You can get Google's icons as SVG, and SVG is "scalable vector graphics". If you are using SVG it doesn't matter the size. An .svg element can take the size of it's container.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SVG attribute -  **shape-rendering =" crispEdges "** to disable browser anti-aliasing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

> **crispEdges**
>
> Indicates that the user agent shall attempt to emphasize the contrast
>   between clean edges of artwork over rendering speed and geometric
>   precision. To achieve crisp edges, the user agent might turn off
>   anti-aliasing for all lines and curves or possibly just for straight
>   lines which are close to vertical or horizontal. Also, the user agent
>   might adjust line positions and line widths to align edges with device
>   pixels.

```html
<svg width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>account balance</title>
<g id="g" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
    <path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'></path>
    <path d='M20.54 5.23l-1.39-1.68C18.88 3.21 18.47 3 18 3H6c-.47 0-.88.21-1.16.55L3.46 5.23C3.17 5.57 3 6.02 3 6.5V19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6.5c0-.48-.17-.93-.46-1.27zM12 17.5L6.5 12H10v-2h4v2h3.5L12 17.5zM5.12 5l.81-1h12l.94 1H5.12z'></path>
</g>
</svg>

<svg width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>account balance</title>
<use xlink:href="#g" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

An .svg element can take whatever size you want.

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg width='15' height='15' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>account balance</title>
<use xlink:href="#g" />
</svg>


<svg width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>account balance</title>
<g id="g">
    <path d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'></path>
    <path d='M4 10v7h3v-7h-3zm6 0v7h3v-7h-3zm-8 12h19v-3h-19v3zm14-12v7h3v-7h-3zm-4.5-9l-9.5 5v2h19v-2l-9.5-5z'></path>
</g>
</svg>

<svg width='48' height='48' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>account balance</title>
<use xlink:href="#g" />
</svg>

<svg width='60' height='60' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>account balance</title>
<use xlink:href="#g" />
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

This is an answer for the OP updated question:

I've made some changes in your code and now you have a 20/20 px svg:
Your icon has a lot of white space around the image. I've removed that space.

```html
<svg width='20' height='20' viewBox='3 3 18 18'><title>account balance</title>
<g id="g">
    <path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'></path>
    <path id="B" d='M20.54 5.23l-1.39-1.68C18.88 3.21 18.47 3 18 3H6c-.47 0-.88.21-1.16.55L3.46 5.23C3.17 5.57 3 6.02 3 6.5V19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6.5c0-.48-.17-.93-.46-1.27zM12 17.5L6.5 12H10v-2h4v2h3.5L12 17.5zM5.12 5l.81-1h12l.94 1H5.12z'></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Updated my question with the snippet based on your answer.

Comment: I updated my answer in base of your updated question

Comment: The point is to get the size of the visible image that matches the reference size (in this case, this is the archive icon from Gmail). Obviously now the icon has become bigger than necessary.

Comment: 20dp = 15 px. In your case if the icon is 24/24 the image inside is 18px. For a 20/20 icon the image inside is 15px: touching the threshold. The image is not blurry. It's your eyes that are unable to see it.